# Map Events From calendar provider to dates in gridview

Tags: java, android, datetime

I working on a calendar app on Android, using [roomaorama](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid), which is nice.

I am fetching all the events from Events table in Calendar provider once which seems not good performance wise.

The library uses a infinite view pager. It uses 4 adapters to display dates.

```
CaldroidGridAdapter adapter0 = getNewDatesGridAdapter(
            currentDateTime.getMonth(), currentDateTime.getYear());

// Setup dateInMonthsList
dateInMonthsList = adapter0.getDatetimeList();

// Next month
DateTime nextDateTime = currentDateTime.plus(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            DateTime.DayOverflow.LastDay);
CaldroidGridAdapter adapter1 = getNewDatesGridAdapter(
            nextDateTime.getMonth(), nextDateTime.getYear());

// Next 2 month
DateTime next2DateTime = nextDateTime.plus(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            DateTime.DayOverflow.LastDay);
CaldroidGridAdapter adapter2 = getNewDatesGridAdapter(
            next2DateTime.getMonth(), next2DateTime.getYear());

// Previous month
DateTime prevDateTime = currentDateTime.minus(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            DateTime.DayOverflow.LastDay);
CaldroidGridAdapter adapter3 = getNewDatesGridAdapter(
            prevDateTime.getMonth(), prevDateTime.getYear());
```

The library uses the date4j library for dates.

I am using asynctask for fetching events from calendar provider. Fetching events based on month change can be done using the below. But what if the user swipes at a faster rate (it's a view pager)?

```
final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {

       /* Do i fetch events here based on month */
        String text = "month: " + month + " year: " + year;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClickDate(Date date, View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Long click " + formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Caldroid view is created",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

MyAsyncTask code

```
private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<Event>> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            events.clear();
        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            Calendar c_start = Calendar.getInstance();

            String millisecond = String.valueOf(c_start.getTimeInMillis());

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,c_start.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
            String emillisecond = String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

            selection = "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND ("
                    + Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
                    + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?) AND (" + "dtstart"
                    + " >= ?))";
             selectionArgs = new String[] { "accountname",
                    "com.google", "accountname", millisecond};
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                    new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                            "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() > 1) {
                do {

                    Event event = new Event();
                    event.setEVENT(cursor.getString(1));
                    event.setDESCRIPTION(cursor.getString(2));

                    event.setStartDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3)));
                    event.setEndDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4)));
                    event.setLOCATION(cursor.getString(5));

                    events.add(event);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();

            }else
            {
                cursor.close();
            }

            return events;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Event> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTimeInMillis(Long.valueOf(result.get(i).getStartDate()));

                Date greenDate = c.getTime();


                if (caldroidFragment != null) {


                    caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.blue,
                            greenDate);

                    caldroidFragment.refreshView();

                } 

            }

        }
```

How the dates are populated?

In the adapter you have a array list of `DateTime`

```
protected ArrayList<DateTime> datetimeList;
```

Then

```
datetimeList = CalendarHelper.getFullWeeks(this.month, this.year,
            startDayOfWeek, sixWeeksInCalendar);
```

Then

```
public static ArrayList<DateTime> getFullWeeks(int month, int year,
        int startDayOfWeek, boolean sixWeeksInCalendar) {
    ArrayList<DateTime> datetimeList = new ArrayList<DateTime>();

    DateTime firstDateOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime lastDateOfMonth = firstDateOfMonth.plusDays(firstDateOfMonth
            .getNumDaysInMonth() - 1);

    // Add dates of first week from previous month
    int weekdayOfFirstDate = firstDateOfMonth.getWeekDay();

    // If weekdayOfFirstDate smaller than startDayOfWeek
    // For e.g: weekdayFirstDate is Monday, startDayOfWeek is Tuesday
    // increase the weekday of FirstDate because it's in the future
    if (weekdayOfFirstDate < startDayOfWeek) {
        weekdayOfFirstDate += 7;
    }

    while (weekdayOfFirstDate > 0) {
        DateTime dateTime = firstDateOfMonth.minusDays(weekdayOfFirstDate
                - startDayOfWeek);
        if (!dateTime.lt(firstDateOfMonth)) {
            break;
        }

        datetimeList.add(dateTime);
        weekdayOfFirstDate--;
    }

    // Add dates of current month
    for (int i = 0; i < lastDateOfMonth.getDay(); i++) {
        datetimeList.add(firstDateOfMonth.plusDays(i));
    }

    // Add dates of last week from next month
    int endDayOfWeek = startDayOfWeek - 1;

    if (endDayOfWeek == 0) {
        endDayOfWeek = 7;
    }

    if (lastDateOfMonth.getWeekDay() != endDayOfWeek) {
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
            DateTime nextDay = lastDateOfMonth.plusDays(i);
            datetimeList.add(nextDay);
            i++;
            if (nextDay.getWeekDay() == endDayOfWeek) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add more weeks to fill remaining rows
    if (sixWeeksInCalendar) {
        int size = datetimeList.size();
        int row = size / 7;
        int numOfDays = (6 - row) * 7;
        DateTime lastDateTime = datetimeList.get(size - 1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
            DateTime nextDateTime = lastDateTime.plusDays(i);
            datetimeList.add(nextDateTime);
        }
    }

    return datetimeList;
}
```

Then in `getView` of adapter you have  a `textview`

```
textView.setText("" + dateTime.getDay());
```

Coloring dates is setting a background for the `textview` (for  dates which has events).

Right now events are fetched once. Based on `starttime` which is in milliseconds we get the date from calendar and color the specific dates accordingly.

I am looking for a better way to map events to dates. I am not sure if the right code fragments have been posted. Do let me know if anything is needed.